# Can not Edit Address Book Record from iphone app

Tags: iphone, edit, addressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I want to edit record from address book in my iphone app. But I can not edit any record. Here is my code

```
 // In my First View Controller

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   DetailViewController *detailViewController=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithRecordObject:record];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}

//------------------------------------

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import "User.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIActionSheetDelegate,ABPersonViewControllerDelegate> {

    ABRecordRef record;
    // Some other ivars
}
- (id)initWithRecordObject:(ABRecordRef)myrecord;

//------------------------------------

@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithRecordObject:(ABRecordRef)myrecord
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        record = myrecord;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Edit Record Method

-(void)btnEditContactTapped:(id)sender {

    // Fetch the address book 
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    ABRecordID recID = ABRecordGetRecordID(record);

    ABRecordRef record1 = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,recID);

    ABPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init];

    // set delegate
    personViewController.personViewDelegate = self;

    // Allow editing info
    personViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

    // Display contact info of selected person
    personViewController.displayedPerson = record1;

    personViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(returnFromPersonView)] ;

    APP_DELGATE.isContactEdited = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];

    [personViewController release];
}

-(void)returnFromPersonView {
    NSLog(@"In %s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

#pragma mark - ABPersonViewControllerDelegate Method

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue {

    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

When I push personViewController , I can't see anything regarding record. Here is a screenshot

[image]

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's [Adress Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html). A page that would be useful to you is the [Direct Interaction: Programmatically Accessing the Database](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1) page. I advise you to just look around at those pages, they are quite self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read the info from link. But its same as what I used to implement. But its not working. I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Have you noticed anything wrong in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing return to YES may help in last method

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue {

//[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO; //try changing it to YES
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the "Correct Contact ID" as `ABRecordRef` ;)